# How to remove gutenberg_render_title_tag from theme function file?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have try remove action but not working.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'gutenberg_render_title_tag', -1 );
}
```

or

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_my_action' );
function remove_my_action() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'gutenberg_render_title_tag', -1 );
}
```

i am using yoast plugin. Yoast plugin also using remove action https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/trunk/src/integrations/front-end-integration.php#L220  but it's not working.  Still  tag coming two time. i wants to remove gutenberg title tag.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_default_guten_title' );

function remove_default_guten_title() {
    foreach ( gutenberg_get_template_type_slugs() as $template_type ) {
        add_filter( str_replace( '-', '', $template_type ) . '_template', 'remove_default_title', 21, 3 );
    }
}

function remove_default_title() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'gutenberg_render_title_tag', 1 );
    return gutenberg_dir_path() . 'lib/template-canvas.php';
}
```